# jQuery FadeIn Placement

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jQuery function to load external content from another page on my server.
I want to add some sleek effects, but I just kind find where I can place a simple **FadeIn**.

Any help would be great.

```
function load2() {
     jQuery('#container').load.('mypage.php', function() { });
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function load2() {
     jQuery('#container').load.('mypage.php', function() { });
       $('#container').hide();
       $('#container').show('slow');

}
```

This should do the trick

Comment: $('#container').hide().load('mypage.php', function() { $(this).show('slow') });